# Relational database - send id value in dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to send the ID of the new selected value from the dropdown list in edit form?
SQL query

```
$id = $_GET['edit'];
    $result = $polaczenie->query("SELECT idwizyty, data, pracownicy.imie, pracownicy.nazwisko, uslugi.nazwa, klienci.imie, klienci.nazwisko, starttime, endtime, reservedendtime, uslugi.cena FROM Wizyty, Klienci, Uslugi, Pracownicy WHERE wizyty.idpracownika = pracownicy.idpracownika AND wizyty.iduslugi = uslugi.iduslugi AND wizyty.idklienta = klienci.idklienta AND idwizyty=$id")
    or die($mysqli->error());
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id = $row[0];
        $data = $row[1];
        $pracownik = $row[2]. ' ' .$row[3];
        $usluga = $row[4];
        $klient = $row[5]. ' ' .$row[6];
        $time = $row[7];
```

and the dropdown list

```
<form action="Wizyty-proces.php?ID=<?php echo $id;?>" method="POST"
<label>Pracownik</label>
                        <?php 
                            $query = "SELECT idpracownika, imie, nazwisko FROM `pracownicy`";

                            $wynik1 = mysqli_query($polaczenie, $query);
                        ?>
                        <select name="nowypracownik">
                            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($wynik1)):
                                $value = $row1[1] .' '.$row1[2];
                                $selected = $value == $pracownik ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
                                <option <?php echo $selected?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </select>
```

Comment: Question is not really clear, but i guess you looking for $_POST['nowypracownik']

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I think what you want is `<option <?php echo $selected?> value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>`

Comment: @tadman yeah i know im gonna edit that later thanks for info!

Comment: @Nick Exactly! Thank you very much!

Comment: @F3jko I wasn't certain based on your code so didn't post as an answer. Given that it works I'll post so question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the `id` value back as the `value` attribute of the `option`. You can do that using by changing this line:

```
<option <?php echo $selected?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
```

to

```
<option <?php echo $selected?> value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>
```